# Relationship of gradient descent step size to the second-order derivative?

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

The update rule in Newton's method is $ x \leftarrow x - \mathbf{H}^{-1} \nabla $, where $ \mathbf{H} $ is the Hessian and $ \nabla $ is the gradient.

In the case of gradient descent, the update rule is $ x \leftarrow - \alpha \nabla $, where $ \alpha $ is the step size or learning rate.

Created this visual (below) for understanding the impact of the learning rate of gradient descent. The orange circle indicates the initial value of $x$. The 'Insights' table shows the first 10 steps of gradient descent for the chosen step size.

For this particular problem, Newton's method suggests a step size (reciprocal of second-derivative) of 0.5. Some observations from this interactive visualization:

- A step size of 0.5 with gradient descent will reach the minimum in one step. (Just like Newton's method would for a convex quadratic function).
- Any learning rate lower than 0.5 leads to slower convergence.
- Any learning rate higher than 0.5 (but less than 1) leads to oscillations around the minimum till it finally lands at the minimum.
- A learning rate $\alpha=1$ for this function. The iterations just keep oscillating.
- A learning rate greater than 1 leads to the iterations moving away from the minimum.

**Now the question is:** "1" is twice the step size of Newton's method for this optimization problem. Will it be the case that a learning rate that is twice (or some other finite multiple) of the reciprocal of the second-order derivative is undesirable for optimization with gradient descent? Is anyone familiar with any research along these lines?

[Gradient descent demo on $ \min x^2 $](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXBPk.gif)

Comment: Generally speaking, the influence of the starting point and the step size in iteration methods are studied in complex dynamics. For example, https://scholarship.claremont.edu/hmc_fac_pub/760/